# Angularjs - How to pass selected radio button value to the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of dynamically generated radio boxes.

```
<div id="Address" class="modal-body" ng-show="AData">
    <h5>
        Select the correct address information from the list below.
    </h5>
    <label class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="address in Addresses">
        <input type="radio" class="SuggestAddresses" ng-model="SelectedAddress" name="grAVR" ng-value="address" />
        {{values.AddressLine1}} {{values.City}} {{values.State}} {{values.Zip}}
    </label>
</div>
```

I am trying to access the model **SelectedAddress** in my controller but its value is undefined in controller. When I store this radiobox model value in a predefined scope variable that is already in my controller, it works fine.

Comment: `ng-model="adress.selectedAdress"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add some explanation to the comment above,  `ng-model="adress.selectedAdress"` will allow you to access the obects property.

Note that you are working with an object in a list, represented by `adress` in your ng-repeat. This corresponds to `Adresses[adress].selectedAdress`

Comment: I am not able to find the $scope.SelectedAddress in my controller after the above changes. but when I store this value in a predefined scope variable e.g.: ng-model = "ModelData.SelectedAddress", the value ModelData.SelectedAddress is easily accessible in my controller. But I can not use ModelData.SelectedAddress as a ng-model here.

Comment: the model will bind to `$scope.Adresses[adress].selectedAdress`, where adress is kind of a placeholder for the object in `Adresses`. So, if `Adresses` contains two objects, each of them will be represented by `adress` in your ng-repeat.

Comment: Just checked, Its worked awesomely. I was not aware that Addresses.selectedAddress would be accessible via $scope. Thanks.